# Semantic class of a word?

Tags: semantics

I read about the term semantic class and I can't quite figure it out.
Can anyone please explain to me with examples when 2 words are in the same semantic class?
Can a plural word can be in the same semantic class of its singular word?
(Cars - Car ?)
And what is the difference between that and topical class?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you've seen the word used? There are several different ways to classify words in semantics.

Comment: I don't believe that _semantic class_ is an established term. (The NoW corpus contains precisely five instances of the phrase in its 15.2 billion words of data, and all five of them talk about the "semantic class of a pixel", and so are about image processing not linguistics). So _semantic class_ will mean whatever the author of what you're reading chooses it to mean.